# Use of dplyr slice_min within a function to obtain row associated with a column minimum value

Tags: r, dplyr, slice

I am trying to create a function that returns the hospital with the lowest death rate for a particular condition.  The inputs to the function are state and condition.  I should also point out I am new to R.  I quite like the functions within the dplyr package but seem to be having a few problems with the use of the slice_min function and passing variables into it.  If anyone can advise what is wrong and how to correct it, would be appreciated.  I will show below two options I have tried which dont seem to work.

Example of function call is:

`best_hospital("CA","HeartFailure")`

The function is

```
best_hospital <- function(state, disease_type){
    library(dplyr)
    library(janitor)

    #Loads data
    data_path <- c('D:/Data Science/CourseraR/Assign3 Info/outcome-of-care-measures.csv')
    data_df <- read.csv(data_path, colClasses = "character")

    #Replaces capitals, spaces and special characters in names
    data_df <- data_df %>% 
            clean_names() %>%
            select(state,hospital_name,
               hospital_30_day_death_mortality_rates_from_heart_attack,
               hospital_30_day_death_mortality_rates_from_heart_failure,
               hospital_30_day_death_mortality_rates_from_pneumonia)

    colnames(data_df) <- c("State", "HospitalName","HeartAttack", "HeartFailure", "Pneumonia")
    
    data_df <- data_df %>%
            filter(State == {{state}} ) %>%
            select(State, HospitalName, {{disease_type}} ) 
    
    # This DOES NOT work   
    # data_df <- data_df %>% slice_min(order_by = {{disease_type}}, with_ties = TRUE)
    
    #This DOES NOT work
    data_df <- data_df %>% slice_min(order_by = HeartFailure, with_ties = TRUE)
    
    print(head(data_df))
```

}

Both methods I have shown above select and return data.  But is not row associated with the minimum value for the column of interest (in this case Heart Failure).  Any help would be welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

best_hospital <- function(data_df, state, disease_type){
 
  data_df <- data_df %>%
               filter(State == state) %>%
               select(State, HospitalName, disease_type) 
  
  data_df <- data_df %>% 
              slice_min(order_by = .data[[disease_type]], with_ties = TRUE)
  
  return(data_df)
}


#Loads data
data_path <- c('D:/Data Science/CourseraR/Assign3 Info/outcome-of-care-measures.csv')
data_df <- read.csv(data_path, colClasses = "character")

#Replaces capitals, spaces and special characters in names
data_df <- data_df %>% 
  clean_names() %>%
  select(state,hospital_name,
         hospital_30_day_death_mortality_rates_from_heart_attack,
         hospital_30_day_death_mortality_rates_from_heart_failure,
         hospital_30_day_death_mortality_rates_from_pneumonia)

colnames(data_df) <- c("State", "HospitalName","HeartAttack", "HeartFailure", "Pneumonia")

result <- best_hospital(data_df, "CA","HeartFailure")
result
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Once I added coercion to numeric as well it seems to work.  I cant find any documentation on what the .data[[disease_type]] is doing and why it is needed in slice_min but not in select or filter.  Are you able to provide any advice?  Thanks again

Comment: In `filter`  we are passing the value on which we want to filter and not the column name. In `filter(State == state)`, `State` is the column name but we are passing `state` which is a value in that column. `select` works both with string value as well as unquoted variable. So `select(State, HospitalName, .data[[disease_type]])`  would work as well. When we pass column names as string variable we need to use `.data`.